# How to remove property from a child element?

Tags: html, css

I’m using an image to replace the regular checkbox element, and the filter property for visual effects when unchecked selected to gray the image.

```css
.ckbx {
  display: none;
}
.ckbx + label {
  background: url('https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/04/11/12/08/check-mark-27820_960_720.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(30%);
}
.ckbx:checked + label {
  filter: none;
}
label span {
  margin-left: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="ckbx" id="bike">
  <label for="bike"><span>I have a bike</span></label>
</div>
```

The problem is that the span is influenced by the filter so we can’t read the text when changing states (checked/unchecked).

How to make the span unaffected by the filter (use native CSS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/z63b6qwL/

You can't remove filter from child element, but you can change your html and css a little:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="ckbx" id="bike">
  <label for="bike"><span class="image"></span><span class="text">I have a bike</span></label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ckbx {
  display: none;
}
.ckbx + label > .image {
  background: url('https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/04/11/12/08/check-mark-27820_960_720.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(30%);
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.ckbx:checked + label > .image {
  filter: none;
}
label span.text {
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Your solution was very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Simply set the background of your label inside a child. You will then be able to style your image like you want without applying style to your text.

```css
.ckbx {
  display: none;
}
.check-item {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.check-item__img {
  background: url('https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/04/11/12/08/check-mark-27820_960_720.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(30%);
}
.ckbx:checked + .check-item .check-item__img {
  filter: none;
}

.check-item__img,
.check-item__text {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="ckbx" id="bike">
  <label for="bike" class="check-item">
    <span class="check-item__img"></span>
    <span class="check-item__text">I have a bike</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is wrong because the text disappears with the image